# How can I structure the URL of a request having multiple parameters in a REST style?

Tags: rest, web-services, restful-url

I have the following problem: I have to develop an API that is as close as possible to the **RESTfull** standard.

This API is related to retrieve some messages about nutritional information and take many parameters (used to perform a query). These are the parameter that I have to provide to my API and that are used to perform the query:

- localization_id
- crop_id
- process_phase_id
- process_phase_action_id
- user_type_id
- urgency_id
- provided_by_id
- cleared_by_id

So, as you can see, it is pretty impossible to put all these parameters in a single URL path.

I think that the **main parameter** is the **localization_id**, the second more important parameter is the **crop_id** (also from a logical point of view a crop is something that is into a country identified by the **localization_id**).

So I was thinking to create an URL like:

```
http://XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAAA/enutrifood/localization_id/crop_id/messages
```

where **enutrifood** is the name of the service that I am calling (the service providing nutritional information), then I specity the country (by the **localization_id** and the **crop_id** in this country. Finnaly I am specifying that I want the list of all the messages. (For example: all the messages for Maize in Senegal). The other parameter can be passed as query parameters, doing something like this:

```
http://XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAAA/enutrifood/localization_id/crop_id/messages?process_phase_id=vale&process_phase_action_id=value&user_type_id=value&urgency_id=value&provided_by_id=value&cleared_by_id=value
```

Could be considered a decent REST compromise to handle a request of this type?

Comment: _So, as you can see, it is pretty impossible to put all these parameters in a single URL path_. What do you exactly mean? If those `ID`s are some 10 digit integers the max len of URL is not even near? How big are those `ID`s?